# Compare two lm() where one is calculated on a subset of the data

Tags: r, regression, lm, anova

I'm trying to compare two linear models, one calculated with full dataset and one calculated on a subset of the same data.
The reason why I need/want to do that is, I suspect a part of the data to cause a shift in the slope.
So here is my dummy dataset.

```
set.seed(5)
x1 <- runif(20, 0, 115)
x2 <- runif(10, 85, 150)
x <- c(x1, x2)

# dependent variable y has two parts with different slopes
y <- c(6*x1 + rnorm(20, 0, 15), 1.5*x2 + 500 + rnorm(10, 0, 15))

# the grouping variables A and B correspond to the first part of y
# grouping variable C to the second part of y
groups <- c(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10), rep("C", 10))

# joining everything together
df <- data.frame(x, y, groups)
```

Plotting the dataframe `plot(df$x, df$y, col = df$groups)` shows that the C group in entirely responsible for a shift in the slope.
I'm trying to see, if leaving out the C group changes the slope significantly.
I tried this by subsetting the dataframe, calculating the linear models, and compare the two models.

```
# first linear model
lm1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
# subset without the C group
df2 <- subset(df, groups != "C")
# second linear model
lm2 <- lm(y ~ x, data = df2)

# comparison of the two models
anova(lm1, lm2)
```

However, running anova gives an error saying that the "models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset"

Is there anyway to compare the two models?

Comment: `anova` compares the effectiveness of one model vs. another model. But you're using the same model. What you want is to examine the **weight** of group C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to test for whether a particular group has changed the slope of a variable is to include dummy variables for groups B and C, and an interaction dummy variable between your x variable and groups B and C.

To do this in R, run the following code:

```
lmtest <- lm(y ~ groups*x, data = df)

summary(lmtest)
```

Comment: couldn't you also simply plot the lm and determine if the influential observations relate to your group? Looking at the various residual plots of OP's lm1, the model fit seems to be quite ok, and rows 21, 28, 30 seem to influence the slope the most. Or am I completely missing the point of the question here?

Comment: Thanks @lilster your answer solved my problem. Don't know, why I haven't thought about adding and interaction term.
Just one little follow-up question.
Doesn't the code `lmtest <- lm(y ~ x*groups, data = df)` produce the same result?

Comment: You are right @OFish, I could have simply plotted the lm. That's how I ended up wondering, how to test if there is a significant change in slope.
My dummy data is very short and group C doesn't do much to the slope. However, my original data was derived by exposing way to many samples to different amounts of stress, resulting in a stronger difference between the model with and without the strongest stressor.

Comment: Ah @tim, you were looking to see if it significantly influences the curve. understood. yes, then the interaction term would be the way I'd look for an answer to that question too.